# pyqtdeploy: Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017

Tags: pyqtdeploy

I'm trying pyqtdeploy for the first time, [following the docs](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/pyqtdeploy/demo.html).

I'm getting the following error when running build-demo.py:

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\Lib\site-packag
es\pyqtdeploy\demo>python build-demo.py
pyqtdeploy-sysroot: Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017.
```

The py file seems to be getting Environment variables from the `os` module, as running the same command in `python console` it works fine. Somehow `pyqtdeploy` is having a problem with this.

I have the build tools installed in the system; what am I missing here?

Comment: Do you have MSVC installed?

Comment: Did you figure it out? I tried every single suggestion I could find, but couldn't fix the error.

Answer (score 4):

You must search the location of the ***vcvars64.bat*** in your Build Tools' folder location and copy it. It depends on your system environment and the version of Visual Studio installed.
Before run pyqtdeploy script, paste that location in the command prompt. This will initialize the Environment and enable the detection of **MSVC x64.**

> ***Step 1*** : Download all the required packages ....

[pic1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mQTR5.png)

> ***Step 2*** : Browse to the directory where Micosoft Visual Studio is installed

[pic2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qH4oV.png)

> ***Step 3***: Search for *vcvars64.bat* in that directory

[pic3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/acyQj.png)

> **Step 4** : Run *vcvars64.bat* and if it successful, run *pyqtdeploy-sysroot sysroot.json*

[pic4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4fNl.png)