# Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017

Tags: python, visual-c++, pyqtdeploy

I'm following the [tutorial](https://docs.huihoo.com/pyqt/pyqtdeploy/tutorial.html#creating-a-pyqtdeploy-project) but when I run `pyqtdeploy myproject.pdy` It shows a popup saying `Unable to detect MSVC2015 or MSVC2017`

I have visual studio 2017 installed with all the c++ components in the installer, I also have Qt installed.

Answer (score 0):

1. Browse to the directory where Micosoft Visual Studio is installed (example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio")
2. Search for vcvars32.bat or vcvars32.bat in Micosoft Visual Studio directory
3. Go to your project directory
4. run vcvarsXX.bat from project directory(example "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio... full path...\vcvars32.bat")
   [image: unable detect]

thanks https://stackoverflow.com/a/60206253/8625835